# Where can I find the nuance/meaning differences between words with different kanji options?

Tags: kanji, homophonic-kanji, resources, dictionary, kanji-choice

This question is related to the questions ([here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/do-people-actually-respect-the-nuances-of-%E6%8E%A2%E3%81%99-vs-%E6%8D%9C%E3%81%99)) and ([here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/same-reading-similar-meaning-different-kanji)) regarding a word or verb with multiple kanji options, for example [作る、造る、創る] or [蔵、倉、庫]

Is there a resource somewhere that will tell me the nuance differences in between the kanji? This can be in English or in Japanese. Teachers will often give me a distinction, but I haven't found a way to look this up myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an official document (「異字同訓の漢字の使い分け例」) that covers a number of these. For example:

> つくる ０８４
>   【作る】こしらえる。米を作る。規則を作る。新記録を作る。計画を作る。詩を作る。笑顔を作る。
>   会社を作る。機会を作る。組織を作る。
>   【造る】大きなものをこしらえる。醸造する。
>   船を造る。庭園を造る。宅地を造る。道路を造る。数寄屋造りの家。酒を造る。
>   【創る*】独創性のあるものを生み出す。
>   新しい文化を創（作）る。画期的な商品を創（作）り出す。
>   * 一般的には「創る」の代わりに「作る」と表記しても差し支えないが，事柄の「独創性」を 明確に示したい場合には，「創る」を用いる。

Or this, which is admittedly a little less helpful.

> くら
>   倉－倉敷料。倉荷証券。
>   蔵－蔵屋敷。蔵払い。

See links from the [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8C%E8%A8%93%E7%95%B0%E5%AD%97) or [online version](http://joyokanji.info/iji.html)

Comment: Note that this list is not exhaustive.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is perfect! Exactly what I wanted.
For others looking, I was suggested [this](http://www.nihonjiten.com/nihongo/doukun/) on another forum. It's an online one. May be less comprehensive than the pdf provided here.

Comment: By the way, the file is gone ... current link?

Answer (score 3):

While **ssb**’s answer is absolutely sufficient, I want to point out—in addition—an English resource that some may not think of in these circumstances.

Of the three current, major kanji–English dictionaries (Nelson, Spahn–Hadamitzky and Halpern), Jack Halpern’s [New Japanese–English Character Dictionary](http://www.kanji.org/kanji/dictionaries/njecd/njecd.htm) is actually rather well equipped with information suited for us beginners.

This is part of page 47 (and a small inset of page 46), covering about a fifth of the total entry for the kanji 作:

[image: Part of page 47 of Jack Halpern’s New Japanese–English Character Dictionary]

While the other kanji dictionaries in English cover more kanji and use a (slightly) more traditional radical look-up method, they come nowhere near the amount of semantic information Halpern covers in this dictionary. They each have their own strengths and weaknesses, and I would like to say that this is Halpern’s strength.

(The latest edition of this dictionary goes under the name [The Kodansha Kanji Dictionary](http://www.kanji.org/kanji/dictionaries/KKD/kaneirev.htm). And it seems to have been expanded by some 1,000 kanji entries, 5,000 senses and 7,000 compunds; as well as some further 1.000 synonym expositions and about 100 additional usage notes.)

Answer (score 1):

One low-budget option is the IME. Microsoft's IME (and possibly others) has little comments next to the homonym kanji that help you to choose the correct one:
[image: Windows XP IME] 
[image: Windows 10 IME]